# How to suggest places to meet using Google places API given a postal code/ latitude & longitude retrieved? (Android)

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

How do I suggest places to meet using Google places API given a pair of latitude and longitude that I managed to retrieve from Google Geocode API converting from postal code?
Looking forward to all the favourable answers!

Comment: Background: Suggest places to meet given 2 postal codes, find the central place, get the latitude and longitude of it and suggest places to meet.

Comment: Please add more detail, such as the code you've already tried and any errors you receive. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the Current Place method that is part of the Places SDK for Android (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/current-place)?